# Como cambiar un input de un tipo a otro con Javascript a través de eventos

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, input, input-type

tengo una duda y es que quisiera cambiar que al hacer dobleclick a un `input` tipo texto cambiara a uno tipo `number`.

Se que en JavaScript tengo a la mano, tales como: `addEvent.Listener("dblclick")` para el evento disparador pero de ahí no se como hacer que ese evento disparador haga que me cambie el tipo de input que tengo que es de texto a uno numero.
gracias por su ayuda y pronta respuesta, cordial saludo!

````
 html: ```<form id="form">
               ``` <input id="input" type="text"> ```
               ``` <input id="input2" type="submit" value="enviar"> ```
               ``` </form>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que cambie de texto a número al hacer doble click, debes añadir un evento **ondblclick** como éste, donde se llame a la función la cual coge el elemento por su ID y cambia el tipo a number.

No sabía si querías que al hacer doble click de nuevo, vuelva a convertirse en type="text"; si es así dímelo y lo actualizo.

Espero que te ayude, puedes darle a **Ejecutar** para comprobarlo por ti mismo.

```js
function cambiaANumero() {
  document.getElementById('input').type = 'number';
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="input" type="text" ondblclick="cambiaANumero()">
    <input id="input2" type="submit" value="enviar">
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero que te ayude, puedes darle a **Ejecutar** para comprobarlo por ti mismo.

Comment: `Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me funciono!

Comment: Me alegro compañero! Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Puedes dar la respuesta como aceptada? Así, si llega alguien nuevo y ve la pregunta, dará con la respuesta correcta de un vistazo, gracias!

Comment: listo ya la acepte

Answer (score 0):

A través de la propiedad `type`.

`input.type = "number";`

Comment: Con hacer un comentario hubiera bastado.